# What is the difference between 当{とう} and この?

Tags: word-choice, kanji, demonstratives

I am making a website and needed inspiration for a "404 not found" page in Japanese.
Going to a non-existent page on Amazon.co.jp (ex: [amazon.co.jp/aaaaaaa](https://www.amazon.co.jp/aaaaa)) gives this message:

> 何{なに}かお探{さが}しですか？
>
> 入力{にゅうりょく}したURLが当{とう}サイトのページと一致{いっち}しません

When I translated it to English with Google translate, it meant:

> Are you looking for something?
> The URL you entered does not match the page on this site

I then clicked the `⇄` to translate the English I just received back to Japanese, and I saw that **当サイト** got replaced with **このサイト**.

I know they both mean "*this website*" but **what is the difference between using *当{とう}* and using *この*?**

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/59672/in-terms-of-this-school-what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%93%e3%81%ae%e5%ad%a6%e6%a0%a1-%e6%9c%ac%e6%a0%a1-and-%e5%bd%93%e6%a0%a1

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that

当= this (business organisation or place)

この =this (something or someone close to the speaker (including the speaker), or ideas expressed by the speaker)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

From my feeling, 当 has a meaning of 'my' or 'our'.

- 当方　= I, me, my side
- この方 = This person (polite way)

Meaning of 当サイト appears to be "this site" and it can be understandable.
But in this case, they are referring to their own site.